# How to display adequate info without looking "busy"

Tags: layout, text, grid

So I'm making a section of a web page for an "event management" system.  The system works as follows:

- The Organizer Email field is an autocomplete.  You start typing an email and it performs an AJAX call to search the DB.
- The event dropdown contains a list of all the event types.  Once you click one it populates the "event information" subbox with information about the event such as it's name, duration, and description.
- When you click on a day in the calendar a list of all available time slots will be displayed for that day.
- Once you click a timeslot I'm thinking a modal will appear if you "Really want to schedule Joe Bob for the Cat event at Sunday 12/26/2015 9:00 PM?"

Here's an example of the layout I made thusfar.  The entire thing just looks too "busy" and "off" for me and I can't wrap my head around why.  Any ideas or suggestions?

This is the entire page with a navbar on top.  It's all pretty simple.

[image]

A mockup of my HTML\CSS\Bootstrap can be found at http://www.bootply.com/WSjk7WKyaf

Comment: It doesn't look that busy to me. To improve it I would hide the calendar until a user clicks an input field or clicks a button like this one found here (Datepicker-popup) https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your event management system is a Calendar application with fixed list of event types and fixed (or single) invitees. So, you may consider to let the user schedule the event right from a Calendar view, like in Google or Outlook Calendar. See for example, how Google let you create an event straight from the Calendar view:

[image: Google Calendar event creation]

In your case you can switch 'What:' with 'Event:' and add another line for the Organizer Email. Event details can be presented in a foldout panel which is closed by default. If one wants to see it, he will open it. we can assume advanced users would like to keep it closed.